# How to add validation with error message in Select using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form for validating my form but not bale to set validation for my select dropdown

```
          <Form.Group>
              <Form.Select
                type="text"
                defaultValue={"default"}
                {...register("role", { required: true })}
              >
                <option value="default" disabled>
                  Select Role
                </option>
                <option value="UI Developer">UI Developer</option>
                <option value="Backend Developer">Backend Developer</option>
                <option value="Python Developer">Python Developer</option>
              </Form.Select>
              {errors.role && <span>Select Role</span>}
          </Form.Group>
```

I tried using the min, max options but that did not work, also tried setting required: "select option" but this did not worked too

Comment: any specific reason you are not wrapping your filed in a [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/)?

Comment: not aware of it, will that solve the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what `Form.Select` is but if it's not a native input it might be easier to use the Controller approach that RHF suggests

Comment: probably because you have a default value assigned to the select `defaultValue={"default"}` which means there's always going to be a value and `react-hook-from` will not trigger the `required` validation, as expected. I'd suggest adding an empty defaultValue `""`